# angularjs route - previous page js not clear

Tags: jquery, angularjs, routes

I use the following code

index.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#!/page1">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#!/page2">Page 2</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {
            templateUrl: "page1.html"
        })
        .when('/page2', {
            templateUrl: "page2.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: "page1.html"
    });
</script>
```

page1.html

```
<div>Page1</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
            alert("page1");
        });
    });
</script>
```

page2.html

```
<div>Page2</div>
```

When index.html run, following step

1. Change the select box to "B", i got "page1" alert.
2. Then click  Page 2, page route to page 2, change the select box to "A", i got "page1" alert too.
3. Then Click  Page 1, page route to page 1, change the select box to "B", i got two "page1" alert.
4. Then click  Page 2, page route to page 2, change the select box to "A", i got two "page1" alert.
5. Then Click  Page 1, page route to page 1, change the select box to "B", i got three "page1" alert.

Seem route stored my js same as route to page 1 times, how can i clean previous page js when route page?

I don't want see "page 1" alert in page 2, and only see "page 1" alert in page 1.

I was try

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
});
```

But not work

Answer (score 0):

You should consider wrapping DOM manipulations in a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) so that you can leverage component lifecycle hooks to register the event listener when the component is created ($onInit) and de-register it when the component is destroyed ($onDestroy).

The following example may be of some help:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.component('pageOneComponent', {
  controller: function() {
    var element = angular.element("#mySelect");
    var handler = function() {
      alert("page1");
    };

    this.$onInit = function() {
      element.bind("change", handler);
    };
    this.$onDestroy = function() {
      element.unbind("change", handler);
    };
  },
  template: '<div>Page1</div>'
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', {
      template: '<page-one-component/>',
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      template: "page2.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
      template: '<page-one-component/>',
    });
}]);
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#!/page1">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#!/page2">Page 2</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i can't do this, because i have so many jquery code in my page, i include it on each template like <script src="template/page1/page1.js"></script>, if i change like your example syntax, will be a very hard work. Sorry but, has any other solutions?

Comment: Hi @Satoshi! Thanks for the feedback, I will get back to you if I figure out another way